# What is a good way to store guest user information that may be saved to a permanent user after registration in django?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I have a RESTful django webapp that allows users to take quizzes in a progressive system where the quizzes become increasingly difficult. Their progress is saved when they answer a question. I'm using django-rest-framework.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass


class IntervalsProfile(models.Model):
    # Belongs to User model in 1-to-1 relationship
    # If User is deleted, then the corresponding IntervalsProfile will be deleted as well
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    level = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    current_level = models.IntegerField(default=0)  # Level the user is currently viewing/on
```

I would like users to be able to play as a guest, and if they so choose, register in order to save their progress. I cannot figure out how to save this guest information or how to save it once they register.

I've searched thoroughly and all the solutions I see are either several years old or seem too cumbersome (such as adding a check for authentication in every view and having 2 cases for each view).

Any advice or guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> if they so choose, register in order to save their progress

1. Subclass django's `User` model and add a new field called `is_guest = BooleanField`. (django has good [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) on how to do this already.)
2. Ask your users to input just a `username` when they visit for the first time. (or you can also assign them a random username using something like [coolname](https://pypi.org/project/coolname/)).
3. Create a `User` instance for their chosen `username` with `is_guest=True` without any password and now you can save all the game information anyway corresponding to this user.
4. Tomorrow, when they choose to register, you can simply update the already existing `User` instance and mark `is_guest=False`.

**EDIT:**

If you don't want the added complexity of your own `User` model, you could also achieve the same without subclassing `User` model and just adding the `is_guest` column to the `IntervalsProfile` model